# Separating constructor definition and declaration when are defult

Tags: c++, constructor

is any point(e.g faster compilation) of separate definition and declaration of default constructor/destructor? I met with such design and I don't understand why someone do not keep it just in .hpp file.

```
// A.hpp
class A
{
public:
    A();
    ~A();
};
```

```
// A.cpp
#include "A.hpp"
A::A() = default;
A::~A() = default;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is done to avoid inlining the constructor and destructor. One reason is when there are members of smart-pointers to incomplete types when their definitions are only available in the `.cpp` file.

There is a difference between defaulting the constructor/destructor in the *declaration* vs the *definition*. The former can be [`noexcept` automatically](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept_spec) whereas the latter has to be declared with `noexcept`. Also, the constructor not *declared* as `default` makes the type non-trivial.

Answer (score 5):

Consider PIMPL idiom implemented with smart pointers:

```
// X.h:
class X {
  class Impl;
  std::unique_ptr<Impl> pimpl_;
public:
  ~X() = default;
  ...
};
```

Inclusion of such a header file into source will cause a compilation error, since `X::Impl` is an incomplete type there and therefore cannot be deleted.

A solution is to move destructor definition into a source:

```
// X.h:
class X {
  class Impl;
  std::unique_ptr<Impl> pimpl_;
public:
  ~X();
  ...
};
```

Plus:

```
// X.cpp:
class X::Impl { ... };

X::~X() = default;  // X::Impl is complete here
```